# Vue Toastify on Nuxt 3 not updating Toast

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I'm trying to get vue-toastify on Nuxt 3 to update the toast, though I'm struggling to make it update even just basic text. Having looked through their docs, I'm updating it correct and the `toastId` is returning the same.

This is my code

```
    const toastId = useNuxtApp().$toast.loading('I'm Loading!...', { timeout: -1 });  
    console.log(toastId)
    useNuxtApp().$toast.update(toastId, {
        render: 'Not loading anymore',
        autoClose: true,
        closeOnClick: true,
        closeButton: true,
        type: 'success',
        isLoading: false,
    });
```

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong here?

https://vue3-toastify.js-bridge.com/usage/update-toast.html#basic-example

Comment: I am suggesting to use https://vue-toastification.maronato.dev/ in your nuxt3 project.

Comment: Not looking for a new module.

Answer (score -1):

The code you provided is a bit complicated. Here are two ways you can implement Vue Toastify in your Nuxt 3 project.

**Method 1** - Most common usage.

`~/plugins/toastify.client.ts`

Don't forget to suffix the file name with `.client`.

```js
import Vue3Toasity, { type ToastContainerOptions } from 'vue3-toastify'
import 'vue3-toastify/dist/index.css'

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(Vue3Toasity) as ToastContainerOptions
})
```

Component usage.

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { toast, type ToastOptions } from 'vue3-toastify'
const notify = () => {
  toast("Hello World 12345", {
    autoClose: 5000,
    position: toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER,
  } as ToastOptions)
}
</script>
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <button @click="notify">Notify !</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<style scoped lang="css"></style>
```

**Method 2**

`~/plugins/toastify.client.ts`

```js
import Vue3Toasity, { type ToastContainerOptions } from 'vue3-toastify'
import 'vue3-toastify/dist/index.css'
import { toast, type ToastOptions } from 'vue3-toastify'

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(Vue3Toasity) as ToastContainerOptions
  return {
    provide: {
      toastify: (msg: string) => {
        toast(msg, {
          autoClose: 5000,
          position: toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER,
        } as ToastOptions)
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Component usage.

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>
const { $toastify } = useNuxtApp()
</script>
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="$toastify('Hello World I am toast.')">Notify !</button>
  </div>
</template>
<style scoped lang="css"></style>
```

Tested and it works. Hope this helps!
[image]